# Missing file when cross-compiling for Amiga on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, ubuntu-16.04, amiga

I am trying to build some software for AmigaDOS 3.x on a ubuntu 16.04 host system, but at link time I get this error:

```
/opt/m68k-amigaos/m68k-amigaos/bin/ld: cannot open crt0.o: No such file or directory
```

The process of building from .c to .o works fine and with no errors. Its only the link stage that displays any error. The link command I am using is:

```
sst:  $(OFILES)
    m68k-amigaos-gcc -o sst $(OFILES) -lm
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add some information about the toolchain you are using, perhaps a link to its download page if applicable?

Comment: Its here: http://fengestad.no/m68k-amigaos-toolchain/

Comment: Do you want the source code? Its at: https://amigacity.xyz/sstsrc.zip - i will keep it there for posterity :)

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered here:
https://github.com/adtools/amigaos-cross-toolchain/issues/12

I will copy/paste it here, in case the original post on Github became unavailable:

You need to use `-noixemul` switch during linking stage, otherwise the toolchain will try to use ixemul startup routine which is not available.

```
$ m68k-amigaos-gcc -noixemul hello.c -o hello
```